# MYSQL: Find Only Full String, Not Subset

Tags: mysql, regex

I am working on legacy software, which, no joke, has had over a dozen people working on it in the past ten years.  And it looks it.

The problem I'm having right now is that some records contain strings for "dance rules", instead of record IDs.  Far too much other code depends on these strings being strings for me to change this.  I don't want to add a new field to the table containing ID codes, which I would then have to constantly correlate to the text field.  I want to leave the table as it is until such time as they give me total control of the project, and let me throw it away and start over.

Here's the issue:  We currently have four dance rules:

- Co-ed
- Prep
- Hip Hop
- Expanded Hip Hop

These rules are kept in the "dance_rules" field of the division-types table, in a VARCHAR field.  The contents of this field is pre-formatted for display:

1. Hip Hop
2. Co-ed & Hip Hop
3. Expanded Hip Hop
4. Prep & Expanded Hip Hop
5. Co-ed, Hip Hop & Expanded Hip Hop

No, these are not the only combinations.

My problem here lies in finding "Hip Hop", but not "Expanded Hip Hop".  I have seen other responses on StackOverFlow which show how to use regular expressions to match substrings, but a search for just "Hip Hop" will always match "Expanded Hip Hop".

Using the examples above, a search for "Hip Hop" should find 1, 2, and 5, but not 3 or 4.  The solution obviously needs to reference the comma and ampersand, but those aren't present with only a single item in the list.  I've just added an add/edit/delete feature (which has been strangely missing for a decade) for this aspect of the code, so I can't depend on the values being in the same order any more.

Comment: Did you try `NOT REGEXP` for pattern **Expanded Hip Hop**  ? see here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_not-regexp

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Record 5 will fail to match with that.

Comment: chris85 year you are right, I have missed that :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
(^|[,&] )Hip
```

to match that requirement, or if there are multiple types of `Hip`:

```
(^|[,&] )Hip Hop
```

This will match if the start of the column has `Hip`, or the column has `Hip` followed by an `&` or `,`.

SQL Usage:

```
select id from dance where class regexp '(^|[,&] )Hip'
```

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8uY57D/1

Finally got SQLFiddle to execute: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f94bb/1

There is information about character classes here, http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html.

Comment: Thanks muchly.  This answer is clean and simple, which makes me embarrassed that I couldn't figure it out for myself.  (To be fair, though, I have never been able to totally grasp the ins and outs of regular expressions.)  Your answer and Midnight's both work, but yours is less typing.

Comment: Nice answer and other support Chris

Answer (score 2):

Try this regular expression. It covers your test cases, and any case where "Hip Hop" comes at the beginning or is preceded by a comma or ampersand.

`set @regexp1 = '^Hip Hop|(,|&) Hip Hop';`

```
Execute:
> select 'Hip Hop' regexp @regexp1

+ ------------------------------ +
| 'Hip Hop' regexp @regexp1      |
+ ------------------------------ +
| 1                              |
+ ------------------------------ +
1 rows

Execute:
> select 'Co-ed & Hip Hop' regexp @regexp1

+ -------------------------------------- +
| 'Co-ed & Hip Hop' regexp @regexp1      |
+ -------------------------------------- +
| 1                                      |
+ -------------------------------------- +
1 rows

Execute:
> select 'Extended Hip Hop' regexp @regexp1

+ --------------------------------------- +
| 'Extended Hip Hop' regexp @regexp1      |
+ --------------------------------------- +
| 0                                       |
+ --------------------------------------- +
1 rows

Execute:
> select 'Prep & Expanded Hip Hop' regexp @regexp1

+ ---------------------------------------------- +
| 'Prep & Expanded Hip Hop' regexp @regexp1      |
+ ---------------------------------------------- +
| 0                                              |
+ ---------------------------------------------- +
1 rows

Execute:
> select 'Co-ed, Hip Hop & Expanded Hip Hop' regexp @regexp1

+ -------------------------------------------------------- +
| 'Co-ed, Hip Hop & Expanded Hip Hop' regexp @regexp1      |
+ -------------------------------------------------------- +
| 1                                                        |
+ -------------------------------------------------------- +
1 rows
```